# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined" discord.js v12

Tags: discord.js

I keep getting a

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined"

when running the `-mute` command for my discord bot. I am following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELquTSRANSs):

And the line causing the error looks identical to his. Here's my code:

```
    const {
    GuildMember
} = require("discord.js")
const BotVersion = require('../package.json').version;
const Discord = require("discord.js");
var botdev = require('../data.json').botdev;
const redis = require('../redis.js')
module.exports = {
    name: 'mute',
    description: "mute",
    execute(async, message, args) {

        const { content, channel, mentions } = message
        const split = content.trim().split(' ')
        const syntax = '-mute <@member> <duration as a number> <m, h, d, or life>';

        if (split.length !== 4) {
            channel.send('Insufficient parameters :no_entry_sign:\n**Syntax**: ' + syntax)
            return;
        }
        
        const duration = split[2]
        const durationType = split[3]

        if (isNaN(duration)) {
            channel.send('Please provide a number for the duration\n**Syntax**: ' + syntax)
            return;
        }

        const durations = {
            m: 60,
            h: 60 * 60,
            d: 60 * 60 * 24,
            life: -1
        }

        if (!durations[durationType]) {
            channel.send('Please provide a valid duration type\n**Syntax**: ' + syntax)
            return;
        }

        const seconds = duration * durations[durationType];

        console.log('MENTIONS:', mentions)
        const redisClient = await (redis)
        try {

        } finally {
            redisClient.quit()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, does the stack trace tell you where the error happens?

Comment: Line 15:31, forgot to include that, sorry.

Comment: Can you add a `console.log(message)` and `console.log(message.content)` at the start of the funciton?

Comment: @Aplet123
[ 'mute', '<@!752989978535002134>', '1', 'm' ]
undefined

Comment: Your function should be `async execute(message, args)` or `execute(message, args)`, not `execute(async, message, args)`.

Answer (score 0):

**The Problem**

Your `async` keyword is in the wrong location. In your code, you've put `async` inside your function's parentheses (`execute(async, message, args)`) which has tricked your program into thinking that `async` is one of your function's parameters.

Essentially, when your main js file is executing this command's code, it calls on the command's `execute` function which is what you provided in your question. So the main js file would be doing something along the lines of: `mutecommand.execute(message, args)`.

When it does this, it has set the value of the *first* parameter of your function to `message` and the value of your *second* parameter to `args`. So when we enter the code in your question, the `async` variable now contains the message, the `message` variable now contains the command's args, and the `args` variable is undefined. Because the command's args are just an array of values, not a `Message` object with a `message.content` property or a `.split()` method, you are getting the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined`.

**Finding the Problem**

Now, this issue should have been fairly straightforward to debug and solve on your own. Let's look at the error message more closely:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
```

What is the error telling us? It's telling us that your code is trying to `split` something that is undefined. So where are you splitting something? There's only one place in your code where this is occurring: `const split = content.trim().split(' ')`. So with this information, the error is telling us that `content.trim()` is undefined (which means that `content` itself must be undefined, due to how `.trim()` works).

So now we know that `content` is undefined. Why is it undefined, where are we defining `content`? Well, we're doing it here: `const { content, channel, mentions } = message`. We didn't get any syntax errors, and that syntax is indeed correct, so `content` is being defined properly. That means the only way `content` could be undefined is if `message` doesn't have a `message.content` property.

So if `message.content` is undefined, and we know that all messages have content, then what is `message`? Well, this is where debugging comes in. You can manually debug this very easily with a simple `console.log(message)`, as suggested in the comments. And when you logged this, you got the following result: `[ 'mute', '<@!752989978535002134>', '1', 'm' ]`.

Well, doesn't that look familiar? That's an array containing your command's name, a mention, a duration, and a duration type. You know, from your command's syntax, that this is an array of your command's args. So now you know that your `message` variable contains your args. This could be caused by one of two reasons: either your command handler is incorrectly calling the `execute` method, or the parameters of your function are messed/mixed up. If you have any other working commands in your bot, you can rule out the first reason, and that clearly identifies the reason you are getting your error (the second reason): "the parameters of your function are messed/mixed up".

If you then proceeded to look at an example/template bot (using the same format that you are using for your bot, unlike the tutorial you are using), and compare its `execute` with your own, you would have quickly and easily figured out what the issue was. You need to learn to go through this type of process on your own, and attempt to solve these simple issues yourself. You can come to StackOverflow if you are still stuck even after trying to debug the issue yourself for a long time, but this isn't the place to go whenever you encounter a problem; try to find a solution on your own first, because you'll find that most problems you encounter have immensely simple fixes.

**The Solution**

This is the change you need to make to solve the error you are experiencing in this question:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'mute',
    description: "mute",
    async execute(message, args) {
```

Please don't just copy and paste this solution into your code. Read the above explanation, understand what the problem was, and understand how you can fix such problems on your own in the future.